# Increasing numbers in html content

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to increment numbers of HTML content and format them as currency, for example: "$ 12.50".

In my case, there is an array of prices and products and the code must access the respective arrays with the intent to select the product, find its price and, if it has no value in the HTML, send the value to an HTML tag, if there is Some value in the html tag, which is incremented to the existing value.

Example:

```
function(product, amount){
// search the index
var index = arrayProduct.indexOf(product);

// points the element by index
var price = arrayPrices[index];

// If the tag is empty, it sends, if there is any value in the tag, it increases
document.getElementById("idPrice").innerHTML = price;
}
```

Comment: So maybe an `if` statement to get the value (or lack thereof) from the tag first, then add that to `price` before your existing final line?

Comment: Incremented, like with one dollar? Or one cent? Or the amount *added* to it?

Comment: Like with one dolar and cents: U$ 1.50 @trincot

Comment: I think you mean *add* instead of *increment*. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to add the price to whatever is already in the *idPrice* element, you could perform these steps:

1. parse the current content by first removing characters which are not part of the number (e.g. the dollar sign);
2. convert it to number, and let an empty string be 0
3. add the price to it
4. format it again as a currency amount
5. place it in *idPrice*

Here is the code that does that:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("idPrice");
elem.textContent = '$ ' + (+elem.textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/, '') + price).toFixed(2)
```

In general is better to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` for non-HTML content.

Also, it would be better if you would maintain the price that is stored in *idPrice* in a numerical variable, so that you don't have to decode the formatted price at every addition.

Here is a simple snippet that allows the selection of a product. When the "add" button is clicked the function is called:

```js
var arrayProduct = ['coffee', 'pizza', 'apple pie', 'wine'];
var arrayPrices = [1.10, 5.13, 3.90, 2.99];

function updateTotal(product){
    // Search the index
    var index = arrayProduct.indexOf(product);
    if (index == -1) return; // exit when product not found
    // There is a match. Get the corresponding price
    var price = arrayPrices[index];
    // Convert the tag content to number, add the price and update the  
    // tag content accordingly
    var el = document.getElementById("idPrice");
    el.textContent = '$ ' + (+el.textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/, '') + price).toFixed(2);
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
    updateTotal(document.querySelector('select').value);
};
```

```html
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option value="coffee">coffee ($ 1.10)</option>
    <option value="pizza">pizza ($5.13)</option>
    <option value="apple pie">apple pie ($ 3.90)</option>
    <option value="wine">wine ($ 2.99)</option>
</select>
<button>Add</button><br>

Total: <span id="idPrice"></span>
```

Comment: The result is NaN

Comment: The html element is:

<div align="center" id="idPreco" class="fonte_preco panel-body">R$ 0.00</div>

Comment: I added a demo snippet. As you can see, it works. Possibly you have another issue in your code or HTML.